# Recursive function of 2D array

Tags: c++

I m using recursive technique to display 2d array, I am treating 2d array as 1 d array but giving me output like address. Please tell me what to do.

```
void data(int i,int arr[2][2],int size){
if(i<4){

    if(i%2==0){
        cout<<endl;
    }
    cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
    data(i+1,arr, size);

}
```

Comment: How exactly is this recursive???  You aren't exactly calling your "data" routine from within your "data" routine.

Comment: @trumpetlicks it is. The function is calling itself.

Comment: What is your question? Why did you tag it C if it's C++?

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev - He must have edited the original question, originally he was calling another function "display" NOT "data".

Comment: Yep, I confirm what @trumpetlicks is saying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to treat this as a 1d array, you must declare it as so:

```
void data(int i,int arr[],int size) {
```

Or:

```
void data(int i,int *arr,int size) {
```

The reason is that otherwise, `arr[i]` is interpreted as an array of 2 integers, which decays into a pointer to the first element (and that's the address that is printed).

Declaring it as a 1-dimensional array will make sure that `arr[i]` is seen as an `int`.

Note that whoever calls this function cannot pass a 2D array anymore, or, put another way, cannot make that obvious to the compiler. Instead, you have to pass it a pointer to the first element, as in:

```
data(0, &arr[0][0], 4);
```

Or, equivalently:

```
data(0, arr[0], 4);
```

This just affects the first call, the recursive call is correct, of course.

In other words, the code should work, you just need to change the declaration of the parameter `arr`

Answer (score 0):

You can not print array like this

```
 cout<<arr[i]<<" ";
```

This will gives you address of first element

If you want to print all elements of array, you need to use loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < 2; j++)  cout<<arr[i][j]<<" ";
```

Comment: I want it recursively

Comment: He said he wants to treat it as a 1D array.

Comment: Dont use recursion for problems like this. Its overkill.